# Socket Bind Exception. Address already in use in Android

Tags: android, sockets

I have an application where my device switches between 2 hotspot profiles. Let's call them HotSpot A and HotSpot B.
I create 2 Server sockets on HotSpot A on ports let's say 23 and 24.
After switching my HotSpot profile to B, tear down of these Server sockets happens and I create 3 Server sockets on HotSpot B ports 23,24 and 25.
Now this works most of the times. But around 10% of the times, I get a Socket Bind Exception on ports 23 or 24 or both.
This is how I am creating Server sockets:-

```
public ServerSocketThread(Context context,String serviceName,int port) throws IOException {
    try {
        mContext =context;
        _serviceName=serviceName;
        socket = new ServerSocket();
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        socket.setReceiveBufferSize(10000);
        localPort=socket.getLocalPort();
        peerHandlerMap= new HashMap<Integer,NSDMessageHandler>();
        Logger.i(NSDConstants.TAG, "Socket Started Port Number " + localPort );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.e(NSDConstants.TAG, "IO Exception while creating server Socket");
        e.printStackTrace();
        socket=null;
        pool.shutdownNow();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I tried an approach where I turn off the hotspot for 20 seconds and then restart the last profile. I thought of giving Server Socket port some time to tear down. But rarely it starts working again. Most of the times I receive the same exception.

I know the cause is probably the old port/address still in use. 
Any solutions ?

Comment: You should close the sockets first.

Comment: `tear down of these Server sockets happens `. What do you mean?

Comment: tear down = closing the sockets.

Comment: It looks as if you are not closing them yourself if you write 'it happens'.

Comment: Okay. But now u know.